# I am looking to solve a problem where I can show up to 20 levels of hierarchal information

Tags: ux-field

I need help with accommodating up to 20 levels of hierarchal data in my UI design. The data is basically how packaging in the supply chain is done. If a supplier is sending items to the buyer it will go in a big container and that big container can contain pallets, cartons, boxes small boxes, and such things up to 20 levels. How do I create a UI design that accommodates this. The table is becoming complicated. Looking forward to ideas that are user friendly

Comment: Please share what you have now